# how to add multiple click event in single string in android

Tags: android

how can i add multiple click event with  single text view . check my xml file i want to click on sanjay and ravi sharam ,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/user_name"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:text="Sanjay is following Ravi Sharma"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look at `ClickableSpan`.

Comment: thanku for reply , please share with me any link about clickablespan